# Meaning of code involving function binding

Tags: c++

Can someone explain what is going on in the below code snippet line by line

```cpp
auto enq_func = [](std::queue<reg_t>* q, uint64_t x) { q->push(x); };
std::queue<reg_t> fromhost_queue;
std::function<void(reg_t)> fromhost_callback =
  std::bind(enq_func, &fromhost_queue, std::placeholders::_1);
```

I think I get the gist of it, that fromhost_queue is a std::queue of each element of type reg_t which was typedef in the beginning of the code as uint64_t and its enqueue functionality is defined using the above three lines something like that.

I have trouble understanding *line 1* as I haven't come across this type of function declaration like `=[](...){...};` is this some sort of shorthand or something

Also, in the bind() part in *line 3*, the first argument is a function(here named as enq_func) that bind will be applied on the second argument mostly used to pass a reference of a queue the enq_func will be applied but the last is an argument which will we enqueued but I don't see the enq_func having any argument

Can someone clarify this?

Comment: could to maybe shed a light on what type of declaring is this in line 1 ``` =(...){...}; ```
as I have only come across function defination as 

```c++

<return_type> <function_name> (<arguement list>){
...body;
}

```

Comment: C++ is complicated enough without this sort of thing going on. It looks like a lot of work to [curry an argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying), perhaps an artifact of the author's inclination towards Ruby-style `extend` to mix in methods to an existing class.

Comment: [What is a lambda expression in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627098/what-is-a-lambda-expression-in-c11)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a slightly overly-complex way to create a function-like callable object that pushes its argument into `fromhost_queue`.  That is, `fromhost_callback(123)` will end up calling `fromhost_queue.push(123)`.

```
auto enq_func = [](std::queue<reg_t>* q, uint64_t x) { q->push(x); };
```

This is a lambda expression that creates a callable object that pushes its second parameter into the queue pointed to by the first parameter.  That is, `enq_func(&fromhost_queue, 123)` will call `fromhost_queue.push(123)`.

```
std::function<void(reg_t)> fromhost_callback =
  std::bind(enq_func, &fromhost_queue, std::placeholders::_1);
```

This creates a new callable object that wraps `enq_func` and automatically supplies its first argument, then stores that in a type-erased `std::function` container.  So `fromhost_callback(123)` will automatically call `enq_func(&fromhost_queue, 123)`.

---

There's no reason to do this in two steps though, a single lambda will do fine.
Assuming there's a good reason to use `std::function` then this will do the same thing:

```
std::queue<reg_t> fromhost_queue;
std::function<void(reg_t)> fromhost_callback =
    [&fromhost_queue](uint64_t x) { fromhost_queue.push(x); }
```